# Matching Dates With SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, left-join

I have two different tables as shown in below and would like to Join them using two columns `Product` and `Date`. The `Table1` has YYYYMMDD Date Format and `Table2` has YYYYMM format. Here in the `Table2` it the last business day of the month. Is there any way to Join those two tables.

**Table1:**

```
Product Date    State
A   20080107    NY
A   20080131    TX
B   20100212    CT
B   20100226    MT
C   20150312    HG
C   20140425    UP
```

**Table2:**

```
Product Date    Country
A   200801  USA
C   201503  AUS
B   201002  UK
B   201704  FIN
C   200605  IRE
A   200805  CAN
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Product Date    State   Country
A   20080131    TX  USA
B   20100226    MT  UK
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The Table1 has YYYYMMDD Date Format"? Dates are dates and don't have any format. Are you storing them as varchar?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do that you cannot? If they are both stored as a date they are comparable no matter the "Date format".

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks for your response. I am not storing as varchar and what I am trying to explain is it has YYYYMMDD

Comment: @Alex_P please include some sample code of the join you are attempting, with your desired output

Comment: @HamishD I am trying to compare the last business day of `Date` of `Table2` with `Date` of `Table1`

Comment: There's no data type I know of that stores only YYYYMM without day -- at least in MySQL. What's the exact data type of that column?

Comment: Could you show us the equivalent of `describe table1` and `describe table2`? That would help with the confusion about what's in these tables. And it's not clear to me what your query is. Why is there no `C` column in the output? Why doesn't `A   20080107    NY USA` show up?

Comment: There is no way to store a date without the day. So what is the output of "show create Table1;" and "show create Table2;" ?

Comment: In your expected output, the "C" should also return because it is matching with table1.

Comment: @KKK @Schwern the output does not match as "c" does not have end of business day in the `table2`

Comment: "201503" from table2 and "20150312"  from table 1 are matching, what about this?

Comment: @KKK In general "201503" represents last business day in the March, 2015. So it does not match with "20150312"

Comment: @Alex_P `A   20080131    TX  USA` is apparently a combination of `A   20080131    TX` and `A   200801  USA`. Ok, makes sense. 20080131 is the last day of 200801 and TX is Texas in the USA. `B   20100226    MT  UK` is apparently a combination of `B   20100226    MT` and `B   201002  UK` . `20100226` isn't the end of the month, that would be `20100228`. And `MT` is usually "Montana" which isn't in the UK. We need you to clarify what you want.

Comment: @SchwernB `20100226` is the end of business day. I just made the `MT` thing please ignore it

Comment: @Alex_P So all you want is which rows in `table1` correspond to the last business day of the months in `table2`?

Comment: @Schwern Yeah and it should also match `Product` from both the tables

Comment: @Schwern The Date is `Int` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all the rows in `table1` where `table1.date` corresponds with the last *business day* of the month in `table2.date`.

I'm going to assume these are [real `date` columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html), despite the formatting. If they're not, convert them to real dates. `table1.date` is already in an acceptable `YYYYMMDD` format so MySQL will convert it for you. `table2.date` can be changed to an acceptable `YYYYMMDD` format with `concat(date, "01")`. Then you can use [MySQL's date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). I strongly suggest you make this conversion permanent by altering the tables, it will make everything simpler and faster.

MySQL doesn't have a last business day, but it does have [`last_day`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) and [`dayofweek`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) (and here is where I sigh about MySQL's inconsistent function name conventions). To get the last business day we find the last day of the month, then what day of the week it is, and subtract as appropriate.

Annoyingly, `dayofweek` returns 1 for Sunday, not 0 which makes things a bit more difficult.

```
case
    -- Sunday, move to Friday
    when dayofweek(last_day('2010-02-01')) = 1 then last_day('2010-02-01') - 2
    -- Saturday, move to Friday
    when dayofweek(last_day('2010-02-01')) = 7 then last_day('2010-02-01') - 1
    -- Weekday
    when dayofweek(last_day('2010-02-01')) in(2,3,4,5,6) then last_day('2010-02-01') 
    else null
end as last_business_day;
```

This would be better done as a stored procedure. Not only does this avoid repetition because we can use variables, it also encapsulate the logic in a neat, testable function. We can also declare it `deterministic` which means MySQL can cache the calculation for the same dates saving some CPU time.

```
create function last_business_day(date date)
returns date
deterministic
begin
    declare last_day date;
    declare last_dow int;

    set last_day = last_day(date);
    set last_dow = dayofweek(last_day);
    return case
        -- Sunday, move to Friday
        when last_dow = 1 then
            last_day - 2
        -- Saturday, move to Friday
        when last_dow = 7 then
            last_day - 1
        -- Weekday
        when last_dow in(2,3,4,5,6) then
            last_day
        else
            null
    end;
end;
```

Now we can ask `last_business_day('2010-02-01')` and get `2010-02-26`.

Armed with this, the query becomes simple.

```
select t1.product, t1.date, t1.state, t2.country
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.product = t2.product and
                  t1.date = last_business_day(t2.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solved SQL:

```
select x.product,x.date,x.state,x.country
from
(select x.product,x.date,x.state,country
from (select product,max(date) date from table1 group by product) t1
join table2 on (left(t1.date,6) = table2.date)
join table1 x on (left(x.date,6) = left(t1.date,6))) x
join (select x.product,max(x.date) date
from (select product,max(date) date from table1 group by product) t1
join table2 on (left(t1.date,6) = table2.date)
join table1 x on (left(x.date,6) = left(t1.date,6))
     group by x.product) y
on (x.product = y.product and x.date = y.date);
```

## Example:

```
mysql> create table table1(product varchar(20),date varchar(8), state varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.41 sec)

mysql> insert into table1 values
    -> ('A','20080107','NY'),
    -> ('A','20080131','TX'),
    -> ('B','20100212','CT'),
    -> ('B','20100226','MT'),
    -> ('C','20150312','HG'),
    -> ('C','20140425','UP');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.13 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> create table table2(Product varchar(20),Date varchar(8),Country varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.33 sec)

mysql> insert into table2 values
    -> ('A','200801','USA'),
    -> ('C','201503','AUS'),
    -> ('B','201002','UK'),
    -> ('B','201704','FIN'),
    -> ('C','200605','IRE'),
    -> ('A','200805','CAN');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.13 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select x.product,x.date,x.state,x.country
    -> from
    -> (select x.product,x.date,x.state,country
    -> from (select product,max(date) date from table1 group by product) t1
    -> join table2 on (left(t1.date,6) = table2.date)
    -> join table1 x on (left(x.date,6) = left(t1.date,6))) x
    -> join (select x.product,max(x.date) date
    -> from (select product,max(date) date from table1 group by product) t1
    -> join table2 on (left(t1.date,6) = table2.date)
    -> join table1 x on (left(x.date,6) = left(t1.date,6))
    ->      group by x.product) y
    -> on (x.product = y.product and x.date = y.date);
+---------+----------+-------+---------+
| product | date     | state | country |
+---------+----------+-------+---------+
| A       | 20080131 | TX    | USA     |
| B       | 20100226 | MT    | UK      |
| C       | 20150312 | HG    | AUS     |
+---------+----------+-------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

## Demo

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ef0e5/11

Answer (score 0):

As per OP, `date` is stored an `INT`. Find the last date of each month ( `FLOOR(date/100)`) for each product on table1 and use that to join with table2.

```
select 
t1.product,
t1.date,
t1.state,
t2.country
from 
table2 t2
join
(select table1.* 
 from table1 join
 (select product, max(date) lastdayOfMonth 
  from table1
  group by product, floor(date/100)) t 
  on table1.product = t.product and table1.date = t.lastdayofMonth ) t1 
 on 
 t1.product = t2.product
 and
 t1.date = t2.date
```

Demo: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2550a4/5)

Comment: Here my column Date is in Integer format. So the above code is not working

Comment: @Alex_P  Revised the solution to work with Date being an integer data type.